# Groupby key segment in Dataweave 1.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have the following requirement for DataWeave in Mule ESB 3.8.4 wherein the `shipDate_n`, `shipMethod_n`, and `trackingNumber_n` will **vary from 1 to n** in the input payload. I need to group the data according to the number after the underscores in the key:

**Input payload:**

```
[{
    "shipDate_1": "2010-01-11T07:00:00Z",
    "shipDate_2": "2010-02-11T07:00:00Z",
    "shipDate_3": "2010-03-11T07:00:00Z",
    "shipMethod_1": "UPS1 Ground",
    "shipMethod_2": "UPS2 Ground",
    "shipMethod_3": "UPS3 Ground",
    "trackingNumber_1": "1",
    "trackingNumber_2": "2",
    "trackingNumber_3": "3"
}]
```

**Required output:**

```
[{
    "trackingInfo": [{
            "trackingNbr": "1",
            "shipMethod": "UPS1 Ground",
            "shipDate": "2010-01-11T07:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "trackingNbr": "2",
            "shipMethod": "UPS2 Ground",
            "shipDate": "2010-02-11T07:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "trackingNbr": "3",
            "shipMethod": "UPS3 Ground",
            "shipDate": "2010-03-11T07:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Mule version: 3 or 4?

Comment: Runtime version is 3.8.4

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#pluck) method to count number of fields say `n` and then iterate for `n/3` times and form keys dynamically for getting data from input. Following code worked for given input

Code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var data = payload[0]
%var dataSet = (sizeOf (data pluck $$ )) / 3
%var startIndex = 1
---
[trackingInfo : [ startIndex[0] .. dataSet] map {
    "trackingNbr": data[("trackingNumber_" ++ $)],
    "shipMethod":data[("shipMethod_" ++ $)],
    "shipDate": data[("shipDate_" ++ $)]
}]
```

Input-

```
[
    {
        "shipDate_1": "2010-01-11T07:00:00Z",
        "shipDate_2": "2010-02-11T07:00:00Z",
        "shipMethod_1": "UPS1 Ground",
        "shipMethod_2": "UPS2 Ground",
        "trackingNumber_1": "1",
        "trackingNumber_2": "2"
    }
]
```

Output-

```
[
  {
    "trackingInfo": [
      {
        "trackingNbr": "1",
        "shipMethod": "UPS1 Ground",
        "shipDate": "2010-01-11T07:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "trackingNbr": "2",
        "shipMethod": "UPS2 Ground",
        "shipDate": "2010-02-11T07:00:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Another way is based on count of  `trackingNumber` fields present in input

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var data = payload[0]
%var dataSet =  sizeOf ((data pluck $$ ) filter ($ contains "trackingNumber"))
%var startIndex = 1
---
[trackingInfo : [startIndex[0] .. dataSet] map {
    "trackingNbr": data[("trackingNumber_" ++ $)],
    "shipMethod":data[("shipMethod_" ++ $)],
    "shipDate": data[("shipDate_" ++ $)]
}]
```

HTH